# Window Following an Image

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, horizontal-scrolling, smooth-scrolling

I am looking to have the window of my program follow a Mario `img` within a range instead of scrolling, in essence removing the slide bar and somehow keeping the window focused on the Mario character (like any 2D side-scrolling video game). Any ideas on how to do this using jQuery or HTML?

You can find my program [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/jh7LD/5/). As seen, I have upper and lower values I want the window to show but I don't have a way to move the screen to show those bounds

**EDIT:** It'd be optimal to move a coin counter, the music play/pause button, and anything else I add at the top of the screen with the window. Could a container `div` do this? Could I just use CSS movement to effect all the elements in the `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I created a temporary variable `moveAmount` in my `moveMario` function, which calculated the distance between my Mario `img` and the variables `upperRange` and `lowerRange`, and moved the `div` containing the coin counter and music play/pause button using the code `$("#id").animate({"left":"+=" + moveAmount + "px"},1);`

For the movement of the actual window, I used the same concept, but used the code `window.scrollTo(lowerRange - (1/10)*winWidth, 0);` (because `lowerRange` was originally defined as `(1/10)*winWidth`)

I am really proud of myself for solving this one after a week of trying different things.

See my working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/NpKgc/31/)!

Answer (score 1):

You could try move the whole page using negative margins and keep the img following the window with `position: fixed`.

Comment: Any chance I could see an example of what you mean? I've already messed around with negative margins a good bit with `position: fixed` and it never seemed to have an effect